# Show headings under subsite in global navigation

Tags: sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2010, I would like to show the headings under a subsite in global navigation.

So it will be like this:

- root

  - subsite1

    - folder1

      - page1
      - page2
    - folder2

[image: taken from www.bloggermint.com/2011/06/pure-css3-multi-level-drop-down-navigation-menu]

Image taken from http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/06/pure-css3-multi-level-drop-down-navigation-menu/

How can I make this happen? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply using Metadata based Navigation. you can create Navigation items in the Term Store and use that navigation for site

[Refer here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15876.sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata.aspx) for more details

Comment: Hi @inferno, I don't see the "Managed navigation" option under global navigation although the publishing feature enabled. Is this applicable to SP 2010 too? I am using SP 2010.

Comment: @VivianLee you will need to configure it then, follow steps given here http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Creating-and-Configuring-Managed-Metadata-Service-Application-in-SharePoint-2013